# How to get last X contents

Tags: nodes

I want to write a function inside a module that will return last 20 contents of type X . is there any drupal ready function ? or shall i use queries ?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the [`db_query_range()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query_range/7) and [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) functions:

```
$args = array(':type' => $content_type);
$sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 AND type  = :type ORDER BY created DESC';
$nids = db_query_range($sql, 0, 20, $args)->fetchCol();

$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use views to get that.

Make sure you sort items descending and limit the result number to be 20.

Comment: Dear down voter, Please specify reason for down voting so we can learn. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no special function for that, so you have to use the query.
This will fetch you last 20 published NIDs of a specific content type, which you can after load as node objects.

```
$last_20_nodes = db_query("SELECT `nid` FROM {node} WHERE `type` = :content_type AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 0, 20", array(':content_type' => 'YOUR CONTENT TYPE'));
foreach ($last_20_nodes as $last_node) {
  // Load the node object.
  $node = node_load($last_node->nid);
  // Continue with your process.
  // To see available properties and values, do a dpm($node).
}
```

Update: as Clive noted below, this might result in a lot of queries to possibly get just a few fields. Depending on your exact needs, it might be better to fetch only fields you need, rather than loading the nodes.

Comment: That will result in a lot of unnecessary db overhead, it's much better to use `node_load_multiple()`

Answer (score 0):

For **Drupal** 8 or 9 you can make use of entityQuery, as seen in the following code.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('type', 'content_type')
  ->range(0,20)
  ->sort('created','DESC');
$entity_ids = $query->execute();
```